# Word for "underproportionalize"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a speech, which has a sentence to the effect of:

> Even as COVID-19 continues to cause people to leave the region for cheaper pastures, resulting decreases in expected salary for remote work often *underestimate* actual decreases in cost of living.

I'm trying to express that one quantity follows another — in this case salaries and cost of living, respectively — but the former often doesn't follow the latter to quite the same magnitude.

Here's a phrase from the sentence above, and a few possible rewordings to better specify the meaning I'm looking for:

> decreases in expected salary often *underestimate* actual decreases in cost of living

> *as cost of living decreases, so does expected salary, but not as much*

> *as expected salary falls following cost of living, it doesn't decrease to quite the same degree*

Non-words that approximate the meaning I'm looking for are:

- underproportionalize
- underfollow
- lagproportion

*Trails* gets close, but indicates time lag rather than "underproportionalizing".

Is there a word for this, or something close?

Comment: It sounds like you're set on a verb, but if not, have you rejected the use of disproportionate?

Comment: @livresque It hadn't crossed my mind that I was implicitly focussed on verbs. That would be a good answer if you would add it as one :)

Comment: @KannE Fixed that typo :)

Comment: Your own term *underestimate* works well here.

Comment: I'd use 'fall short of'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for verbs, it sounds like *skew* or *undercut*  would point to the inaccuracy of misleading information and the resulting distortion.  Another fitting term would be *disproportionate*.

From your speech,

> decreases in expected salary often *skew* actual decreases in cost of living

Skew v. 2. Make biased or distorted in a way that is regarded as inaccurate, unfair, or misleading. [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/skew)

> as cost of living decreases, so does expected salary, but *disproportionately* so

Disproportionate: Too large or too small in comparison with something else. [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/disproportionate)

> as expected salary falls following cost of living, this decreases at a *disproportionate* rate

In this sense, *understate* would work just as well in your first sentence, as well as *misconstrue,* *trivialize,* *underemphasize,* and other synonyms for underestimate.